# Updating User Meta with Array on Click of Button AJAX

Tags: ajax, user-meta

I have an array on a front end page, and I am trying to update user_meta with the array via AJAX on the click of a submit button. I have come up with the following code, but I am having problems with it. Currently when I hit submit, I get a 404 error: `POST http://www.....com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request)`

Here is what I got so far:

**Form Example**

```
<form name="myform" id="myform" method="POST">
<input name="user_categories[]" id="<?php echo $box_id ?>" value="<?php echo $box_val ?>" <?php echo $selected ?> type="checkbox"/>
<input name="myBtn" class="ajaxsubmitbutton" type="submit" value="Save Settings">
</form>
```

**The Following is in a Plugin:**

```
      add_action( 'wp_footer', 'cf_ajax_save' ); // Write our JS below here

      function cf_ajax_save() { ?>

        <script type="text/javascript" >
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('.ajaxsubmitbutton').click(function(){
        var user_categories = user_categories
        var data = {
            action: 'aj_save_category_settings',
            user_categories: user_categories
        };

        //ajaxurl is defined only because buddypress predefined it, and points to admin-ajax.php
        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
        });
      });

  });
</script>
 <?php
   }


  function aj_save_user_categories( $user_id ){
     if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) { return false; }
     update_usermeta( $user_id, 'user_categories', $_POST['user_categories'] );
     wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response
 }

 //Hook Function into WP_Ajax for Admin and Frontend
 add_action('wp_ajax_aj_save_category_settings', 'aj_save_user_categories');
 add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_aj_save_category_settings', 'aj_save_user_categories');

  ?>
```

Comment: Have you considered using a REST API endpoint instead? I notice you have a `$user_id` argument on your save users categories function, but AJAX endpoints don't pass parameters, and none of the documentation or examples do this, so where is this value coming from? Also, `nopriv` runs for logged out users, who by definition do not have a user ID

Comment: Try changing `var data = {
            action: 'aj_save_category_settings',
            user_categories: user_categories
        };` to `var data = JSON.stringify({
            action: 'aj_save_category_settings',
            user_categories: user_categories
        });`

Comment: @TomJNowell Thanks for your response! I am new at ajax and I'm not sure what you mean by using a "REST API endpoint". About the `$user_id`, how should I pass that value? Also, I though `nopriv` was required for the function to work on the frontend. I guess not.

Comment: @FahamShaikh Thanks for your response! I tried that, but it did not work.

Comment: `nopriv` is required for it to work for users who aren't logged in, your code uses the old Admin AJAX interface, the new REST API endpoints use a different mechanism

Comment: @TomJNowell I appreciate you explaing that to me. I just took a look at the WP REST API docs but I can't really make any sense of it. Would you mind helping start me off or pointing me to a tutorial? Thanks!

Comment: @Edegist Can you remove the `$user_id` parameter from callback function please.

Comment: @FahamShaikh Thanks, I tried that, but still get the 404

Comment: @Edegist What value are you passing in `user_categories`?

Comment: @FahamShaikh I am passing Category IDs and checkbox selected values

Comment: You are passing actual category value here `var user_categories = user_categories` right, like `var user_categories = 123`?